# Is there any difference between SHA256.Create() and HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA-256")?

Tags: c#, cryptography, sha256, hashalgorithm

Do these two code blocks return the same thing? Assume `arr` is the same `byte[]` in both examples:

**Code sample 1**

```
HashAlgorithm a = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA-256");
var result = a.ComputeHash(arr);
```

**Code sample 2**

```
SHA256 b = SHA256.Create();
var result = b.ComputeHash(arr);
```

**UPDATE**:
I got the sample project of creating AWS signature code in C# (which is written in .Net 4.5) and am trying to use its classes in a dotnetcode5 project and just because `HashAlgorithm.Create()` is not available in dotnetcode5 yet, I have decided to use the second approach instead of the first one. The problem is that the second example returns a canonical result witch is not valid in AWS.

Comment: So, it seems you should be asking *why* is there a difference between those two snippets and not *whether* there is a difference judging by your comment on the first answer.

Comment: how are you comparing your byte arrays ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SHA256.Create()` does this internally:

```
return (HashAlgorithm) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256");
```

`HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA-256")` will result in this:

```
return (SHA256) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("SHA-256");
```

Both of these calls will result in the creation of an instance of [**`SHA256Managed`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256managed(v=vs.110).aspx).

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptoconfig(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5

So there is no difference between these two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Both will result the same because the do call the same method internally

```
new static public SHA256 Create() {
    return Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256");
}

new static public SHA256 Create(String hashName) {
    return (SHA256) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(hashName);
}
```

---

```
static public HashAlgorithm Create(String hashName) {
    return (HashAlgorithm) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(hashName);
}
```

the difference is just the return type (`SHA256` is derived from `HashAlgorithm`)

[Reference for SHA256](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/sha256.cs,fbe4a1ea2a5fc5f4), [Reference for HashAlgorithm](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/hashalgorithm.cs,2d63896aa55de7de,references)

Answer (score 1):

I think the main question that OP is missing is how to compare the two bytes array.

If you do something like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        byte[] arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sample");
        HashAlgorithm a = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA-256");
        var resulthash = a.ComputeHash(arr);

        SHA256 b = SHA256.Create();
        var resultsha = b.ComputeHash(arr);

        Console.WriteLine(StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(resulthash, resultsha ));
    }
```

you will get correct response.

Note you can't do something like `resulthash==resultsha` that will return false.